# Using separate credentials in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have work and private repos on my Windows PC. Both work and private repos can be either Bitbucket or Github.

Whenever I push to private repos the commits are pushed with work credentials.

I'd like to setup TortoiseGit so that pushing to work repo with work credentials runs without password and pushing to private repos with private credentials requires a password.

Is it possible considering Bitbucket and Github now only use token-based authentication?

NB, I don't mind pushing work repos in TortoiseGit and private ones in command line, I'm just trying to figure out a way to keep private repos protected and their commits pushed with correct credentials.

Comment: have you considered using ssh as transport (and so use ssh certificates)?

Comment: @eftshift0 I am willing to use whatever transport and method. I'm just completely lost with all the tutorials and explanations I've read recently. I hope someone can explain me what steps exactly I should  take to have password-less and password-protected repos on the same machine.

Comment: Are you using ssh or https as transport?

Comment: For SSH see https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to eftshift0 and MrTux for the useful comments. I'll summarize the steps of creating password protected GitHub repo with SSH access:

```
Generate a key with optional passphrase
    cd $HOME\.ssh
    ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "USERNAME@mail.com"

Copy contents of the generated id_ed25519.pub and add it to GitHub account
    Account > Settings > SSH and GPG keys > New SSH key > Paste the key

Test the key is working
    ssh -T git@github.com

Clone your repo via SSH
    git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519" clone git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO.git

Add key to repo configuration
    git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_ed25519"

Optionally add local repo author
    git config user.name "USERNAME"
    git config user.email "USERNAME@mail.com"

Test Github access works
    git pull
```